# Sql query for selecting 2 item from 1 table

Tags: sql

I have 2 tables nodes and edges like this

```
NodeID | Node
--------------------
1      | That
2      | Means
3      | a
4      | SIMM
```

Edge table:

```
source | target | weight | type 
---------------------------
1      | 2      | 2      | undirected
1      | 3      | 1      | undirected
3      | 4      | 1      | undirected
```

I tried to select name of source and target with this query but it doesn't work

```
SELECT N1, N2
FROM NODE,
     EDGE
WHERE EDGE.SOURCE = NODES.NODE_ID AS N1
  AND EDGE.TARGET = NODES.NODE_ID AS N2
```

I want the output like this

```
That means
That a
```

How can I do?

Comment: Tip of today: Switch to modern, explicit `JOIN` syntax! Easier to write (without errors), easier to read and maintain, and easier to convert to outer join if needed.

Comment: 'doesnt work' is vague. Is it an error? Is it a different result than you expect?

Answer (score 0):

This will get you that output (joining in `Node` twice.. once for the `source` and once for the `target`.

```
SELECT n1.node, n2.node
FROM 
    node n1
    INNER JOIN edge e ON n1.nodeid = e.source
    INNER JOIN node n2 ON e.target = n2.nodeid
WHERE n1.nodeid = 1
```

You may find yourself wading into recursive CTE's (if your database supports it) if you need to traverse your nodes/edges deeper than this.

Some of the issues in your original SQL:

1. You try to alias... something in your WHERE clause `WHERE EDGE.SOURCE = NODES.NODE_ID AS N1`. This makes no sense. In the query above I alias the `node` table as both `N1` and `N2`. This is (and the SELECT clause) is where Aliasing occurs. You can't just shove an alias anywhere.
2. You attempt to use the bum alias up in your `SELECT` when you say `SELECT N1, N2`. Since the only place you can alias a column is in the SELECT (and you haven't done so) this won't work. You can refer to table aliases in the `SELECT` clause if they have been defined in the `FROM` as I have done in the above query. You still have to reference the column in the alias though.

Answer (score 0):

try following:

```
SELECT SN.Node, TN.Node
FROM EDGE AS E
JOIN NODE AS SN
ON SN.NODE_ID = E.SOURCE
JOIN NODE AS TN
ON TN.NODE_ID = E.TARGET
```

You need to join `NODE` 2 times when you want to display source and target information.

Answer (score 0):

You could join each EDGE field to a particular NODE table, like this:

```
SELECT n1.NODE, N2.NODE
  FROM NODE n1,
       NODE n2,
       EDGE e
  WHERE e.SOURCE = n1.NODE_ID 
    AND e.TARGET = n2.NODE_ID
```

Answer (score 0):

```
With CTE as (
     SELECT * NODE 
)
SELECT c.Node N1,cc.Node N2 from Edge
  left join CTE c on Edges.source1=c.NodeID
  Left Join CTE cc on Edges.target1=cc.NodeID
```